# React - passing props to children

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to find proper way to write the TableWrapper component. I want to be structured something like this when using it. Could you please help me how to pass the props from the parent to the children?

```
          <TableWrapper
        loadData={loadData}
        data={data}
        isExternalOpen={isExternalOpen}
        setIsExternalCreate={setIsExternalCreate}
        setIsExternalOpen={setIsExternalOpen}
        showEmptyState={false}
        limit={4}
        loading={loading}
      >
        {({ dispatchHandler, isOpen, setIsOpen, data, previousPage, nextPage }: TableWrapperComponentInterface) => (
          <>
            <Table
              title={title}
              onCreateHandler={onCreateHandler}
              columns={columns}
              data={data}
              previousPage={previousPage}
              nextPage={nextPage}
              actions={[actions]}
            />
            <TableModal isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} setIsCreate={setIsCreate}>
              <>Doesn't matter</>
            </TableModal>
          </>
        )}
      </TableWrapper>
```

I have something like this but that doesn't seem right. I would be glad if somebody could help me. :)

```
export const TableWrapper = (props: TableWrapperInterface) => {
  const {
    children,
    loadData,
    setIsExternalCreate,
    setIsExternalOpen,
    emptyStateAddButtonTitle,
    emptyStateButton = true,
    emptyStateText,
    showEmptyState,
    loading,
    data,
    limit = 10,
    isExternalOpen,
  } = props

  ...
  
  const Component = children


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Component
      dispatchHandler={dispatchHandler}
      setIsOpen={setIsExternalOpen}
      isOpen={isExternalOpen}
      data={sendData}
      loadData={loadData}
      previousPage={previousPage}
      nextPage={nextPage}
    />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default TableWrapper
```

Comment: What issue are you having? If you don't want to "prop-drill" you can always use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use Context in this case. Whats "prop-drill"?

Comment: Prop drilling is when you add a prop to each parent in the tree until you get to the component you need the prop in. The link above should explain how context works.

Comment: Ohh, okay. So for example Formik is using Context?

Comment: I  have updated my question.

Comment: What you're trying in your sample is called render props and it's documented here: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: @digitalbreed Thank you! So it seems that my code is alright. My problem is that I'm using [Headless UI](https://headlessui.dev/react/dialog) as modal. And when updating state outside of TableWrapper and then passing it to TableWrapper and then the props to children via render props it's not working as it should. Exactly the animations are gone.